# Trying to get my navigation next to my logo

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my nav next to my logo and it just keeps putting it below it. My code isn't great, but I want the nav to be next to the logo like I have in the design that I have:

[image]

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="backgroundofdivgreen">
<header>


<div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.jpg"></a></div>    

    <nav>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="services.html">Services</a>
    <a href="offers.html">Offers</a>
    <a href="people.html">People</a>
    <a href="franchises.html">Franchises</a>
    <a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a>
    </div>

</header>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-color:blue;
}

.backgroundofdivgreen {
    height: 96px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #39b54a;

}

header {
    width: 980px;
    height: 96px;
    background-color: #39b54a;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

nav {
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Actually, using float positionning is not recommended, as it wasn't designed for this, but for images or lettrines within a text. You should consider using the 'position' property, or grid/flexbox layouts (if possible, be careful with compatibility). Also, `display: inline-block` could help you here :)

Answer (score 0):

Apply `float: left;` to the `.logo` class and close your `<nav>` with `</nav> . not with``:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.backgroundofdivgreen {
  height: 96px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #39b54a;
}

header {
  width: 980px;
  height: 96px;
  background-color: #39b54a;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="backgroundofdivgreen">
    <header>


      <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.jpg"></a>
      </div>

      <nav>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="services.html">Services</a>
        <a href="offers.html">Offers</a>
        <a href="people.html">People</a>
        <a href="franchises.html">Franchises</a>
        <a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a>
      </nav>

    </header>
  </div>
```